RaspberryPi dpkg: error processing archive /libc6_2.31 Broken pipe
today i was updating my Pi when i came around this weird error
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:armhf (2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8) over (2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/audit/sotruss-lib.so' (which was about to be installed): Bad message
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have tried:
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8_armhf.deb 
(this errored too

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8_armhf.deb
)

My sourcelist
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
